# while loop not terminating when user presses "n"

Tags: powershell, while-loop

I'm trying to create a menu using a `while` loop.  I want the menu to run till the user presses "n" or "N".

```
$MenuChoice

while ($MenuChoice -ne "n" -or $MenuChoice -ne "N") {
    Write-Host "Run again? y/n "
    Read-Host $MenuChoice
}
```

The problem is that, it runs whether I press "N" or "Y".

Do I need to declare a value for `$MenuChoice`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the output of `Read-Host` to `$MenuChoice`:

```
# Initial value (in case this is run more than once)
$MenuChoice = $null
# This comparison is not case-sensitive
while ($MenuChoice -ne 'n') { $MenuChoice = Read-Host 'Run again? [y/n]' }
```

Comment: Thank you, so what does the $null do?  It tells powershell it have no value yet?

Comment: @TonyAntony it initializes the variable so that it exists. Try `Get-Variable TestVar`, it will return an error. Then do `$TestVar = $null` and try again. You'll see the difference.

Comment: @TonyAntony an alternative would be `Remove-Variable MenuChoice`. It ensures there is no value in the variable that might prematurely trigger the loop exit condition. You can avoid the need for this by using the do loop as suggested by briantist.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, building on [Chris Dent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829981/3905079), use a `do {} while ()` loop:

```
do { 
    $MenuChoice = Read-Host 'Run again? [y/n]' 
} while ($MenuChoice -ine 'n')
```

(also using `-ine` to be explicit about the case insensitive comparison, even though `-ne` is case insensitive by default)